# TypeScript error 'Type '($event: any) => void' is not assignable to type' when listening for an event in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Component code:

```
<h2 @click="handleEvent(post.id)">{{ post.title }}</h2>

function handleEvent(id: number) {
  router.push("/post/" + id);
}
```

Typescript error:

```
Type '($event: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent'.ts(2322)
__VLS_types.ts(107, 56): The expected type comes from property 'click' which is declared here on type 'EventObject<undefined, "click", {}, MouseEvent | undefined>'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Which library are you using for Vue typing? This appears to be inconsistent with the behavior expected for Vue3.

Comment: The problem is specific to IDE, the question doesn't make sense for Vue+TS in general.

Comment: I think I'm having the same error when trying to build with vue-tsc running `vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build`

Comment: @Terry I am using `"vue-tsc": "^1.0.4"` and IDE complains with the similar error on event handlers, my volar version is `Vue Language Features (Volar)
v1.0.7`, downgrading Volar to 1.0.4 did not help

Comment: Looks like an error of some package to me, but I have no idea who the culprit is. I also tried to downgrade vue, vite, typescript and vue-tsc without success.

Answer (score 12):

As I understand in this [issue](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1985) we have 2 options:

1. add @types/node: '18.8.0'
2. wait until this [change](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/6855) is merged into a vue 2.7 release

**note:** Don't use the `^`, fix the version to `18.0.0`

I install the @types/node fixed version and works for me.

Comment: Exactly, it's a bug. It broke my build this week, and I had to downgrade `@types/node` to 18.8.0, which fixed it. They said Vue 3.2.41 would fix it, but it didn't; the issue was closed, but instead of fixing the problem, it just displays a warning on the screen... I really hope they work on this, because the handling, so far, has been a shitshow.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Downgrade `@types/node` to `18.8.0` until `vue 3.2.41` is released.

We've run into the same issue over the last few days but think we've got a solution.

Turned out to be a conflict between `vue 3.2.40` and `@types/node 18.8.5`.
The current version of vue isn't compatible (but `3.2.41` should solve this) with the latest node types.

Steps I did to fix the issue:

1. Revert `@types/node` to `18.8.0` without `^`
2. Remove node modules - here's a handy script we use for this: `find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -print -exec rm -rf '{}' \\;` because we're using a yarn workspaces monorepo
3. Reinstall dependencies
4. Reload VS Code - `cmd+shift+p` turn search for `Developer: Reload Window`

Answer (score 3):

We were facing the same problem - all event handlers in template are erroneous. It appeared a few days ago.
Based on the typescript definition, the event handler must return types "Event" or "MouseEvent". Therefore, we have corrected it in the template as follows:

```
<h2 @click="(e : MouseEvent) => {handleEvent(post.id); return e;}">{{ post.title }}</h2>
```

It works, but does not seem to be the way how event handlers should be written...

Comment: vue 3.2.41 is released but the problem still exists :(

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, @types/node 18.11.10 broke Vue typecheck for events, but a new version has been published and it's now fixed:

- https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1985#issuecomment-1283723657

So, simply upgrade your @types/node dependency.